# MySQL alternative for PLs' foreach in case of VARCHAR's array

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops, cursor

I have a lot of tables in which one or more columns' cells containsvalues for updating.
I have to update all such data, and all my concrete scripts are similar. For example, for updating values for first table for the first column i wrote the script below:

```
SET @old_url := 'lalafo.kg';
SET @new_url := 'olx.kz';

# SELECT * FROM `wp_wm_trees` WHERE tr_title LIKE concat('%', @old_url, '%');
UPDATE `wp_wm_trees` SET tr_title = replace(tr_title, @old_url, @new_url)
    WHERE tr_title LIKE concat('%', @old_url, '%');
```

And for updating values for the second column within the same table i have an identical script with a difference in the column name:

```
# SELECT * FROM `wp_wm_trees` WHERE tr_link LIKE concat('%', @old_url, '%');
UPDATE `wp_wm_trees` SET tr_link = replace(tr_link, @old_url, @new_url)
    WHERE tr_link LIKE concat('%', @old_url, '%');
```

I want to write the universal MySQL script that will process all set columns' names. I want to list VARCHAR values like array in php or javascript and process in the cycle identical snippet, substituting the column name changing in a cycle.

In php it would look something like this:

```
$columns = ['tr_title', 'tr_link', 'tr_thumbnail_url'];
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    ...
}
```

I want to get the same behavior using MySQL. But MySQL doesn't have arrays and doesn't have any cycle with the same syntax like php / javascript foreach.

After that I want to extend my script to changing table name. I need to store in some variable information about tables and their columns for updating. Like below (in php):

```
$toProcess = [
    'table_1' => ['tr_title', 'tr_link', 'tr_thumbnail_url'],
    'table_2' => ['tr_1', 'tr_2',],
    'table_3' => ['tr_first', 'tr_second', 'tr_third'],
    ...
];
foreach ($toProcess as $table) {
    foreach ($table as $column) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can i do it using MySQL?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a client language for example PHP? It seems like you already know how to implement that. SQL isn't a general-purpose programming language, it's a domain-specific language for data manipulation.

Comment: Writing a script with MySQL tools takes ~5 minutes for someone who owns the capabilities of MySQL. And such a script will solve the problem in a matter of seconds within the entire database. I don’t see anything rational in involving a high-level programming language - this will entail the execution of unnecessary subtasks: adding a model layer (too many tables and too many entities), implementing CLI commands, the application itself will not be used, since the task is one-time.

Comment: I write single-use data-maintenance scripts frequently. You don't need an ORM, or models, or whatever. I've used PHP, Ruby, Python, or even Bash. Just open a connection and use a simple `query()` function to execute SQL.